# Get differences between two flat arrays and merge with duplicated values in one array

Tags: php, arrays, string, duplicates, array-difference

I have two strings and I need to compare the words of the each sentence.
The strings are this two:

```
$correctSentence = "The year stations are summer, winter, spring and fall.";

$textSentence = "The year stations are four summer, winter and spring and summer.";
```

So, I make arrays of each sentence and I have the next arrays to compare the words who are no similar between sentences.

```
$correctArray = ["The", "year", "stations", "are", "summer", "winter", "spring", "and", "fall"];

$textArray = ["The", "year", "stations", "are", "four", "summer", "winter", "and", "spring", "and", "summer"];
```

I'm comparing the arrays in this form:
With a for loop, I compare every word of the $textArray with the words of `$correctArray`.

And if the word of `$textArray[$i]` is not similar to any word of `$correctArray`, that word is stored in a new array called `$finalArray`.

```
$finalArray = [];
for($i=0; $i<count($textArray); $i++){
     if(!in_array($textArray[$i], $correctArray)){
           array_push($finalArray, $textArray[$i]);
     }
}
```

The results of $finalArray are this:

```
$finalArray = ["four"];
```

But I need to store in `$finalArray` also the words that are duplicated in `$textArray` like this:

```
$finalArray = ["four", "and", "summer"];
```

Because "and" and "summer" are duplicated in the `$textSentence` and `$textArray`, so that words don't are similar to the words of `$correctSentence` and `$correctArray`

I'm thinking the solution is delete the similar word of `$correctArray` when the if condition is true in this section:

```
$finalArray = [];
for($i=0; $i<count($textArray); $i++){
     if(!in_array($textArray[$i], $correctArray)){
           array_push($finalArray, $textArray[$i]);

           //In this section, delete the word of $correctArray 
           //which is similar of $textArray[$i]. 
           //For example: After comparing "summer" of $textArray[$i] with "summer" of $correctArray. 
           //The  record "summer" of $correctArray should be deleted.
           //And this way the following record "summer" of $textArray (which is duplicated) 
          //should be stored in $finalArray
     }
}
```

Comment: Using iterated `in_array()` calls is typical the least performant way to compare two arrays.  PHP offers its own optimized native call -- `array_diff()`.  Potentially faster would be to flip the arrays and make key comparisons (if that doesn't ruin data due to duplicate value collisions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count the looped string/word appear inside `$textArray` using `array_count_values()` and check if the counted value is more than 1 (means duplicate) than insert into `$finalArray`, also maybe before insert to `$finalArray` you need to check if the string/word already exists inside `$finalArray` or not.

```
$finalArray = [];
    
for($i=0; $i<count($textArray); $i++){
    if(!in_array($textArray[$i], $correctArray)){
        array_push($finalArray, $textArray[$i]);
    }

    // count how many times the string appear in the array
    $total_string_in_array = array_count_values($textArray)[$textArray[$i]];
    if ($total_string_in_array > 1) {
        // check if the duplicate string already exists inside $finalArray
        if ( ! in_array($textArray[$i], $finalArray)) {
            array_push($finalArray, $textArray[$i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Reference:

- array_count_values(): https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP has native functions for everything that you need for this task.

1. Extract words from the sentence without punctuation with `str_word_count()`.
2. Find differences between two flat arrays with `array_diff()`.
3. Count the occurrences of values in an array with `array_count_values()`.
4. Remove elements that have a value (count) less than 2 with `array_filter()`.
5. Get array keys with `array_keys()`.
6. Merge two arrays with `array_merge()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/eGNVI))

```
$correctSentence = "The year stations are summer, winter, spring and fall.";

$textSentence = "The year stations are four summer, winter and spring and summer.";

$correctArray = str_word_count($correctSentence, 1);
$textArray = str_word_count($textSentence, 1);

var_export(
    array_merge(
        array_diff($textArray, $correctArray),
        array_keys(array_filter(array_count_values($textArray), fn($v) => $v > 1))
    )
);
```

Comment: If this answer is not correct for all scenarios in your project, please update your question with a better [mcve] to represent the uncaught exception to the rule.

Comment: Dear no-comment-dv'er, I have proven my answer to be correct.  There is no benefit in wasting your rep because I do not delete my correct answers.